# Cannot find latex.fmt or pdflatex.fmt

Tags: errors, htlatex

Honestly I am about to snap. I don't know - I installed TeX Live yesterday, 2019 version for Windows and I spent over 8 hours trying to figure out why it's not working.

I keep getting these errors every time, I do not know why I have no clue. All I want is to just get LaTeX into PNG, heck just a readable output, just that, I have ImageMagick installed, everything, the latest and greatest but why it won't work I have no clue.

And also these

```
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `flex.dvi'
--- error --- Can't find/open file `flex.dvi'
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `tex4ht.env'
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `flex.lg'
```

Here is my simple sample TeX file:

```latex
\begin{document}
  $f(t) = 4k(\frac{t}{D})^{3}$
\end{document}
```

Here's what I tried typing into cmd:

```
htlatex flex.tex
pdflatex flex.tex
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Before crying, please show us what you tried (what command, for example), and what went wrong _exactly_ (error messages are really helpful).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik i updated it. if there is anything missing do let me know, i also tried using gitex a python package https://pypi.org/project/gitex/ and this to https://www.nawouak.net/?cat=informatics.tex2png+lang=en which just gets stuck. i just want anything i can work with, nothing all i am getting is just errors. i installed the 6440 smth mb of texlive

Comment: Thanks, that should help. The error message you have says ``Can't find/open file `flex.<ext>'``, while your command line says `htlatex ex.tex`. It seems some file name is off. I get a similar error message if I try `htlatex this_file_does_not_exist.tex`...

Comment: you should use `make4ht` instead of `htlatex`. you would probably get a better error messages. You example has missing `\documentclass`, but it shouldn't produce the error message you got.

Comment: @michal.h21 ```c:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\make4ht\make4ht:7: module 'make4ht-logging' not found:
        no field package.preload['make4ht-logging']
        [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'make4ht-logging'
        [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'make4ht-logging'
C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:907: command failed with exit code 1:
texlua c:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\make4ht\make4ht flex.tex``` that's the output. it did have a class i deleted it to see if it'll work. not sure if that would obstruct the process i tired using online tools and they run it fine

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik sorry this was a typo

Comment: what files are in `c:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\make4ht\`? There should be `make4ht-logging.lua` in this directory. It seems to me like a broken installation.

Comment: @michal.h21 it does exist in ```C:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\make4ht\make4ht-logging.lua```

Comment: so it should be found. what does command `kpsewhich make4ht-logging.lua` say?

Comment: @michal.h21 nothing. however if I do enter it with the path it returns the path

Comment: and what about `kpsewhich latex.fmt`? If it cannot find anything, your distribution is broken and may need to be reinstalled.

Comment: @michal.h21 i am getting nothing, and cannot find it within my path. i'll reinstall it then. thanks alot for your time

Comment: @michal.h21 Probably `kpsewhich latex.fmt` does not show
anything also in your case. A right command to find `latex.fmt` is
`kpsewhich -format=fmt -engine=pdftex latex.fmt`

Comment: @AkiraKakuto ah, you are right